# Is the infinite dihedral group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism, dihedral-groups, free-product

Let $a,b$ denote the generators of the copies of $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in the free product $\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2$.

The infinite dihedral group is described by: $$D_{\infty} = \; \left<r,s \;|\; srs=r^{-1}, s^2=1 \right>$$

I have seen that one may define an isomorphism:
$$\phi\colon \mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2\to D_\infty,$$ by
\begin{eqnarray*}\phi(a)&=&rs,\\ \phi(b)&=&s.\end{eqnarray*}

My question is, can we define an analogous map $$\widehat{\phi}\colon \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}\to D_\infty,$$ by
\begin{eqnarray*}\widehat{\phi}(\hat{a})&=&rs,\\ \widehat{\phi}(\hat{b})&=&s,\end{eqnarray*}
where, $\hat{a},\hat{b}$ denote generators of the copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the free product $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.

If this map is well defined, then is it an isomorphism?

Comment: How do $x,y$ relate to $r,s$?

Comment: @ahulpke I have updated the text. thank you

Comment: Use $\times$, `$\times$` for the Cartesian product.

Comment: In $D_\infty$, we have an element $s$ that squares to the identity. Do we have such a similar thing in $\mathbb{Z}\ast\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If you map $(0,1)$ to $s$, then $(0,2)$ is in the kernel.

Comment: What do you mean by the asterisk symbol, $G*H$, Adam?

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is simply false. What's the reason you want to prove it?

Comment: @GerryMyerson it is the free product.  I don't know who edited my question without a permission? and why?

Comment: @MoisheKohan it is not false, this is free product not cartesian product

Comment: @Adam_math: Yes, I know the difference. The free product $Z*Z$ is the free group of rank 2, hence, is torsion-free, while the infinite dihedral group contains elements of order 2, hence, they cannot be isomorphic. But the question remains, why are you trying to prove that they are isomorphic?

Comment: @tkf, the original statement was to prove that $D_{\infty}$ is isomorphic to the free product $\mathbb{Z}_2 * \mathbb{Z}_2$.. I think the same map works as an isomorphism. Right?

Comment: @tkf, and should I prove that my map is well defined?

Comment: @tkf, sorry for the too many questions, but why "the square of the image of each generator is the identity" leads to the wee-defined property of the map? I know if two preimages equal implies that their images also equal, is proving the well-defined, right?

Comment: One user edited your post to improve the formatting, Adam, and another user edited to add some tags. No one edited to change the content (until @tkf, more recently). No one needs your permission to edit your post; users just need to have accumulated enough points to earn editing privileges. The $Z*Z$ that threw everyone off was in your original post; no one put that there but you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your map $\widehat{\phi}$ is well defined.  The elements $\hat{a},\hat{b}$ freely generate $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$, so you can define $\widehat{\phi}$ just by specifying where $\hat{a},\hat{b}$ go.

Note this situation is different to the map $\phi$, as there the elements $a,b$ generate $\mathbb{Z}_2*\mathbb{Z}_2$ subject to the relations: $$a^2=1,\qquad b^2=1.$$
Thus once you specify $\phi(a),\phi(b)$, you need to check that $\phi$ respects these relations.

That is you must check that $$\phi(a)^2=1,\qquad \phi(b)^2=1.$$
Note that both of these equations are true: $$(rs)^2=1,\qquad\qquad s^2=1,$$ in $D_\infty$.

So defining the map $\widehat{\phi}$ is in a sense easier than defining $\phi$ was.  However, unlike $\phi$, the map $\widehat{\phi}$ is not an isomorphism.

In fact it is not injective.  The elements $1, \hat{b}^2\in \mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ both map to the same element $1\in D_\infty$.

In fact it is impossible to construct an isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}\to D_\infty$, because the groups are not isomorphic.  Whilst $s\in D_\infty$ squares to $1$, there is no non-trivial element in $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$ which squares to $1$.